# Rails ActiveRecord: way to chain ActiveRecord_Relation objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In an attempt to keep my code flexible and clean, I would like to be able to pass an ActiveRecord_Relation object to a method that will then "apply" it to another Relation.  Is there a way to take one relation object, chain it to another one, and then apply it to the model?

E.g. in one part of my code I'll do this:

> rel = Employee.where('salary > 100000')

then I want to pass this relation object to another part of the code that would do something like:

> some_employee_relation_object.apply(some_other_employee_relation_object)

The reason I want to do this is I believe it's more appropriate to pass around Relation *objects* than query strings or other derivative representations of the query.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create scopes in your model and chain them.

`scope` example:

```
# employee.rb

scope :big_salary, -> { where('salary > 100000') }
scope :male, -> { where(gender: 'male') }
scope :florida, -> { where(location: 'Florida' }
```

Then you just call it like `Employee.big_salary` in your controller, getting back an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object.

> .. then I want to combine those two objects into a Relation that
>   represents all male employees from Florida

For that you just chain your scopes: `Employee.male.florida`, also getting back an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object.

You can check the guides [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

Comment: Thanks, yeah I RTFM'd and am familiar with scopes and that usage, but, for reasons I won't get into here, they don't offer the flexibility that I need.  I would prefer to find a way to pass around ActiveRecord_Relation objects.

Comment: (Sorry just getting back to this thread).  I have clarified the question to make more clear what I want to do, which is to essentially apply one Relation object to another.  So one part of my code might create a Relation representing all male employees, and another part of the code creates a Relation for all Florida employees ... then I want to combine those two objects into a Relation that represents all male employees from Florida.  (I prefer not to refactor to use scopes btw.)

Comment: @bethesdaboys I've updated the answer to show how your example could work, but i'm still using scopes, since i think they are great fit for what you are looking for. Why you don't like to use scopes?